# How to optimize an airfoil for a 600-lb ultralight design?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I'm designing an ultralight for a wind tunnel test in SketchUp, and I was wondering if there was a mathematical method to optimizing the length and chord of a simple wing that would be located at the top of the body. I felt this location was best so that the airflow moving over would be as undisturbed by the rest of the body as possible. Should I use a program like Autodesk Flow first? I can run it @ 60fps for up to 1200 particles.

Comment: If your idea is to try to simulate the hydrodynamic flow of air over an airfoil by studying a simulation with only 1200 particles acting as air molecules, that's not going to work.

Comment: I meant to use the simulator as a rough estimate only. I would definitely prefer and probably require an in depth answer.

Comment: I don't think that the proposed method would work even as a rough estimate. The problem is that your 1200 particle simulation corresponds to the airfoil moving through a fairly high vacuum with particles having an extremely long mean free path comparable to or greater than the size of your airfoil. That puts your simulation in a completely different hydrodynamic flow regime than air at atmospheric pressure.

Comment: This is Autodesk Flow. The 'particles' are only visual representations of different resolutions, I'm pretty sure all proper laws of physics and fluid dynamics are considered in the numbers provided.